# Can sender of a multicast receive it from the router instead of ip_layer loopback?

Tags: macos, sockets

I am trying to multicast messages from one device to many, and I have a problem with the loopback feature in the IP_LAYER.

My aim is that all devices should receive the message at more or less the same time, but the sender of a multicast will get the message first because it is looped back by the IP_LAYER.

I want the sender to get the message from the router as all the other devices on the subnet.
Is this possible?

If I disable [IP_MULTICAST_LOOP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/ip.4.html) on the socket the sender does not receive the message at all.
I had hoped that this option just disabled the loopback.

Is it possible to do this any other way, I have tried broadcasting as well.
But this also use the loopback function of the IP_LAYER.

Comment: I would think a hub _might_ send the message back to the sender, but a switch would not due to associating the sender's MAC address with the port your machine is connected to.

Comment: thanks, I will see if I can find a hub and test it. I would however prefer a software solution if one is possible.

Comment: I would think multicast packets would only be transmitted on each network link once, so it wouldn't ever be retransmitted back to the sender's link a second time, either by a hub or a router.  I haven't worked with multicast much, though.